# How to add custom label with dynamic value in k6 logs with log-output forwarding?

Tags: label, load-testing, grafana-loki, k6

The default message format for k6 with `console.log` is

```
time="2023-07-19T10:40:20Z" level=info msg="hello" source=console
```

I want to modify this message and let's say add a custom label like `trace=1234 method=login`

I want to do this because the logs will be sent to Loki and then I can search by labels like method

How can I achieve this?

I know, I can achieve this by creating a custom javascript extension with a custom log method. I have tried this like following for testing purposes:

```
package tracelogger

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.k6.io/k6/js/modules"
)

// init is called by the Go runtime at application startup.
func init() {
    modules.Register("k6/x/tracelogger", new(TraceLogger))
}

type TraceLogger struct{
}

func (l *TraceLogger) Log() {
        currentTime := time.Now()
        formattedTime := currentTime.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00")
        fmt.Printf("time=\"%s\" level=info trace=1234 method=abc msg=\"%s\" source=console", formattedTime,  "hello")
}
```

Now in the JS test file

```
import tracelogger from 'k6/x/tracelogger';

export const options = {};

export function setup() { }

export default function LoadTest() {
  tracelogger.log();
}
```

It does print the output but in the standard console as expected

```
time="2023-07-19T12:08:18Z" level=info trace=1234 method=abc msg="hello" source=console
```

Now the problem is I am also forwarding the log output to Loki

```
k6 run --log-output=loki=http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push,label.qa=k6 test.js
```

The log does not get forwarded to Loki, how do I log so that the log gets forwarded to loki?

I also tried with `--log-format=raw` and direct console.log

```
console.log(`trace=1234 msg="aaaa"`);
```

but the labelling doesn't work correctly in loki
[image]